# Javascript regex: issue when trying to parse both http and https instances of a natively archived string URL

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

for example, consider,
 what regex code is one supposed to use to get the last URL in the string , that is "iskme" in the above URL.

Example 1:

string 1-> "https://web.archive.org/web/204534534534645/http://www.iskme.org:80/"

result-> iskme . org

string 2 -> "https://web.archive.org/web/24534534642321/https://www.nytimes.com"

result: nytimes .com

what will be the common regex code for the above two examples:
I am currently using http:?//\w\w\w?\S+.\S\S\S

This regex is satisfying example 1 but fails in Example 2, where it fails to parse the 2nd string during the instance/occurrence of "NYTimes" main content URL.
I am new to Regex and tried to find the answer within google and understood that I needed to add the HTTP(s)? condition. But, it still seems to fail, can anyone point me in the right direction so I can solve this problem, Thank you in advance.

Comment: You posted a link to an image containing text... that's frowned upon here. Please type out your question full.

Comment: Your regex needs an `s?` (i.e.: none or one `s`) instead of your `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler expression should do the trick:

```
var str = "https://web.archive.org/web/20030328195612/https://www.iskme.org:80/";
var url = str.match(/.*(https?:.*)/)[1];
```

The first `.*` will consume as many characters as possible up until the last occurrence of `http(s):` in the search string.

Comment: Than you. oh, can it recognize https too ?

Comment: @RakeshNagaChinta Indeed it can.  `s?` in the expression represents an optional `s` character.

Comment: Thank you ! :) @buttonupbub

Comment: oh, can it work for this string: "https://web.archive.org/web/20030328195612/http://www.iskme.org:80/" , please note that iskme.org has http and not https.

Answer (score 0):

Answer above by @buttonupbub does the trick.

But if you need, for any reason, to store both urls for use after any string parse:

```
'https://web.archive.org/web/20030328195612/https://www.iskme.org:80/'
    .split('http')
    .reduce((acc, curr) => { 
      if (curr) { 
         acc.push( 'http' + curr ) 
      } 
      return acc; 
     }, []); 
 // returns ["https://web.archive.org/web/20030328195612/", "https://www.iskme.org:80/"]
```

Making a lot of assumptions about the data here.